# Related to sys.stdin.readline() in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

For following snippet of python 3 code When I am giving "Level" as my input string it is returning 3 as output whereas expected output is 2.

```
import sys

print("Enter a String and I will tell you about it")


str = sys.stdin.readline()


print(int(len(str)/2))
```

Comment: Have you looked at `repr(str)`? Note that it's a bad name, as it shadows the built in type.

Comment: Yup, changing variable does not affect the output.

Comment: I didn't say it would, but renaming it means you can still access the built-in. Again, *have you looked at the repr?*

Answer (score 1):

It contains `newline` at the end:

```
import sys

print("Enter a String and I will tell you about it")

string = sys.stdin.readline()

print(int(len(string)/2))
for char in string:
    print('{}: \'{}\''.format(ord(char), char))
```

Gives:

```
Enter a String and I will tell you about it
Level
3
76: 'L'
101: 'e'
118: 'v'
101: 'e'
108: 'l'
10: '
'
```

Use `rstrip()` for this.

```
import sys

print("Enter a String and I will tell you about it")

string = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()

print(int(len(string)/2))
for char in string:
    print('{}: \'{}\''.format(ord(char), char))
```

Gives:

```
Enter a String and I will tell you about it
Level
2
76: 'L'
101: 'e'
118: 'v'
101: 'e'
108: 'l'
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's really bad practice to use system var names for variables.

You're problem is with the readlines part, entering level and pressing enter sets your

str= 'level\n'

The '\n' only registers as one character so the total length is 6, giving expected output of 3. To fix use

str = sys.standin.readline().rstrip()

Comment: Thank you, I am new to python but from now onwards I will not use system var names for variables.

Comment: You can get away with it for small things, but it can cause serious problems as python looks for how to variable is defined in the current scope first, moving it's way outwards until it finally gets to system defined. This means you can overwrite objects like str() with reference variables. It can be hard to pick up on if you've been using the same interactive prompt for a while and forgot you overwrote earlier in the day.